# Errors trying to run Android integration test via Appium

Tags: java, android, maven, appium

I have an integration test for an App I am writing that I had working a few weeks ago that has consistently failed since I updated my Android SDK. The issue does not seem to be in the test itself but something to do with Appium. I get two different types of failure depending on how I start up my Appium instance.

If I use the Appium.exe that I installed from their site, I get the following message from the command line tool:

```
> ERROR: error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find zipalign in tools, platform-tools, or supported build-tools under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"; do you have android SDK or build-tools installed into this location? Supported build tools are: 17.0.0, 18.0.1, 19.0.0, 19.0.1, android-4.2.2, android-4.3, android-4.4
> warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
> info: Cleaning up android objects
> info: Cleaning up appium session
> info: Error: Could not find zipalign in tools, platform-tools, or supported build-tools under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"; do you have android SDK or build-tools installed into this location? Supported build tools are: 17.0.0, 18.0.1, 19.0.0, 19.0.1, android-4.2.2, android-4.3, android-4.4
>     at ADB.checkSdkBinaryPresent (C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\adb.js:94:10)
>     at ADB.checkZipAlignPresent (C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\adb.js:137:8)
>     at ADB.zipAlignApk (C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\adb.js:451:8)
>     at null.<anonymous> (C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\adb.js:445:26)
>     at C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:610:21
>     at C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:249:17
>     at iterate (C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:149:13)
>     at C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:160:25
>     at C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:251:21
>     at C:\AppiumForWindows-0.18.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:615:34
> info: Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find zipalign in tools, platform-tools, or supported build-tools under \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\"; do you have android SDK or build-tools installed into this location? Supported build tools are: 17.0.0, 18.0.1, 19.0.0, 19.0.1, android-4.2.2, android-4.3, android-4.4)","origValue":"Could not find zipalign in tools, platform-tools, or supported build-tools under \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\"; do you have android SDK or build-tools installed into this location? Supported build tools are: 17.0.0, 18.0.1, 19.0.0, 19.0.1, android-4.2.2, android-4.3, android-4.4"},"sessionId":null}
> POST /wd/hub/session 500 155095ms - 748b
```

This then causes my maven build to fail.

If I run appium via command line from the git repository of theirs that I pulled from I get the following error from the node server:

```
C:\Appium-Dev\appium>node . --address 127.0.0.1 --platform-name Android --platform-version 17
info: Welcome to Appium v1.2.0 (REV 6b24a459060f8e8352ed4f3a8bcc26b2c507dac5)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
debug: Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"17"}
info: LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"automationName":"syncstuff-android","app":"C:\\netbeans-workspaces\\syncstuff-android\\syncstuff-andr
debug: The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. :
debug: No appActivity desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
debug: No appPackage desired capability or server param. Parsing from apk.
debug: Using local app from desired caps: C:\netbeans-workspaces\syncstuff-android\syncstuff-android-app\target\syncstuff-android-app.apk
debug: Creating new appium session 056709ff-26ba-47fb-84a8-6b15b21da2ec
info: Starting android appium
debug: Using fast reset? true
debug: Preparing device for session
debug: Checking whether app is actually present
debug: Checking whether adb is present
debug: Using adb from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
info: Retrieving device
debug: Trying to find a connected android device
debug: Getting connected devices...
debug: executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
debug: 1 device(s) connected
info: Found device emulator-5554
debug: Setting device id to emulator-5554
debug: Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
debug: executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
debug: executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
debug: Starting logcat capture
error: Logcat capture failed: spawn ENOENT
debug: Stopping logcat capture
```

And while this error does not explicitly fail my build, that build doesn't do anything further after this until it times out +/- 20 minutes later.

Here are my capabilities

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "PhoneFourTwo");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName","android-app");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.companyName");
capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", ".MainActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the zip align problem by copying it to the tools and platform-tools. It's not the best solution but the best I have.

Comment: You are correct, this does work, and I agree that it doesn't seem like the best solution. If anybody else has another suggestion that would be awesome, but for now, this got my test running again.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem yesterday you have white spaces in your path to your SDK Folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Move your SDK folder to a Path, where are no white spaces just like C:\SDK or something like this.

Comment: better solution is you just use the Path variable surrounding with quotation marks